# What is time complexity of following?

Tags: algorithm, loops, time-complexity, big-o, nested-loops

```
int j = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
           while(j < n && arr[i] < arr[j]) {
               j++;
           }
       }
```

Can anybody explain its time complexity in a more intuitive way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   int j = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       while(j < n && arr[i] < arr[j]) {
           j++;
       }
   }
```

In the given code the value of variable `j` is initialized to `0` out side both the loops. Inside the inner loop the value of variable `j` always gets incremented. If `arr[i] < arr[j]` then the value of `j` gets incremented by `1` otherwise the content of the inner loop will note get executed. Notice that the value of `j` can never be more than `n`. Hence the complexity of the given code fragment is always **O(n)**.

Comment: Yes, and I think it would make the answer clearer if you state that `j` can never get larger than `n`.